# Maximal path problem

Tags: graph-algorithm

Given oriented unweighted graph and the problem is to find simple path of maximal length
(start vertex and end vertex are not fixed). It obviously can be solved in O(n^2 * 2 ^n) but I heard that there is O(n * 2 ^ n) algorithm which I don't know. So how to solve it in O(n * 2 ^n)?    //n = |V|

Comment: Wikipedia says for an acyclic graph this problem is O(|V| + |E|).  Does your graph have cycles?  (ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem)

Comment: @jtdubs isn't this comment actually the correct answer?

Comment: also, if graph has cycles; solution for max length is infitinty :D

Comment: I was hoping there was something I was missing that made the question harder than just going to wikipedia... :)

Comment: Hah.  Yes.  Good point about cycles.  Feel silly for missing that.  :)

Comment: Graph may has cycles. In the problem the path must be simple i.e. without selfintersections.

Answer (score 5):

If your problem really is the [Longest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) on a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), the algorithm from Wikipedia is below and runs in O(|V| + |E|):

```
algorithm dag-longest-path is
    input: 
         Directed acyclic graph G
    output: 
         Length of the longest path

    length_to = array with |V(G)| elements of type int with default value 0

    for each vertex v in topOrder(G) do
        for each edge (v, w) in E(G) do
            if length_to[w] <= length_to[v] + weight(G,(v,w)) then
                length_to[w] = length_to[v] + weight(G, (v,w))

    return max(length_to[v] for v in V(G))
```

Comment: this gives back just length of path; wiki has more info how to get actual path

Comment: Graph may has cycles. (otherwise it is trivial problem ;) )

Comment: Answer is finite because path must be simple i.e. without selfitersections